OAUTH2 using google apps script for linking
I'm trying to get my google home action re-certified.  In the original (approved) and new (rejected) the linking url is a google apps script.
They're rejecting my update because I must show a signin page.
The problem is my app runs under my project and my google id or the user's google ID on android.  There is no separate signin ID required.
If I try to show the google sign-in (which they recommended) it refuses to work because my app script runs on a prohibited domain: "script.googleusercontent.com",  Of course it does, because it's an app script!  The script is configured to run as the google user.
I don't have a separate domain or server, everything is done using google cloud functions.
Am I missing something?  They're sending me in circles - I can't log in the user in with a separate id, I can't (re) log in the user to google.
